# Built in Binary Conversion in Scheme/Lisp

Tags: scheme, lisp

Is there a built in binary to decimal conversion function in Scheme?

I've found the built in `number->string` conversion which can convert binary to decimal form.

However, the opposite `string->number` doesn't convert decimals to binary string like I'd thought.

Is there a built in function or would we have to define it?

Answer (score 6):

The `string->number` function accepts an optional `radix` parameter:

```
(string->number "1001" 2)
==> 9
```

Answer (score 5):

Binary and decimal are representations of numbers; numbers themselves are not binary or decimal.

`number->string` converts from a number (such as twelve) to a string (such as "12"), outputting the number's base 10 representation by default.
(It does not convert from binary to decimal - its name describes what it does.)

`string->number` converts from a string (such as "12") to a number (such as twelve), interpreting the string as the base 10 representation of a number by default.
(This function's name also describes what it does.)

You can pass a second argument to both functions for a different base representation (2,8,10, or 16).

To get a string with the binary representation of the number `n`, use `(number->string n 2)`.
To get a number from a string `s` with its binary representation, use `(string->number s 2)`.

Examples:

```
> (number->string 120)
"120"
> (string->number "120")
120
> (number->string 120 2)
"1111000"
> (string->number "1111000" 2)
120
> (number->string 120 16)
"78"
> (string->number "78" 16)
120
```

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp

As with Scheme, numbers does not have bases in Common Lisp as well, only their representations.

Visualizing a number in a base using [`write-to-string`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_to_.htm#write-to-string):

```lisp
(write-to-string 10 :base 2)
; ==> "1010"
```

Reading a  number represented in a certain base using [`parse-integer`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_parse_.htm#parse-integer):

```lisp
(parse-integer "1010" :radix 2)
; ==> 10
; ==> 4 (index where the parser terminated)

(parse-integer "1010.1" :radix 2) 
; parse-integer: substring "1010.1" does not have integer syntax at position 4

(parse-integer "1010.1" :radix 2 :junk-allowed t) 
; ==> 10
; ==> 4 (index where the parser terminated)
```

Alternatively you can use the reader/printer, however reading only works if the next token cannot be interpreted as a float:

```lisp
(let ((*print-base* 2))
  (prin1-to-string 10))
; ==> "1010"

(let ((*read-base* 2)) 
  (read-from-string "1010"))
; ==> 10
; ==> 5

;; *read-base* ignored when interpreted as float
(let ((*read-base* 2)) 
  (read-from-string "1010.1"))
; ==> 1010.1 
; ==> 6
```

I assume global [`*print-base*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_bas.htm#STprint-baseST) and [`*read-base*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_rd_bas.htm) is both ten.
`read-from-string` doesn't care if there is junk after the number so it behaves as `(parse-integer "1010" :radix 2 :junk-allowed t)`

As an added info on the read base doc. You can tell the reader for literals for base 2, 8 and 16 and arbitrary which overrides the dynamic setting:

```lisp
#b1010            ; ==> 10 (base 2)
#o1010            ; ==> 520 (base 8)
#x1010            ; ==> 4112 (base 16)
#3r1010           ; ==> 30 (base 3)
#36rToBeOrNotToBe ; ==> 140613689159812836698 (base 36)
```

Comment: Also, reader syntax for arbitrary radix (from 2 to 36): `#36rToBeOrNotToBe`

Comment: @coredump I totally missed that. Love it :)

Comment: Be very careful about using the reader on data you do not fully control, such as user input.  It is possible to set things up so it at least should be safe, but the default configuration allows code-injection attacks.